# How should I apply this type of patch?

Tags: linux, bash, patch

Some patches are provided as just

```
317c317
<                global $wgScript, $wgUser, $wgParser, $wgTitle, $wgOut;
---
>                global $wgScript, $wgUser, $wgParser, $wgTitle, $wgOut, $wgLocalTZoffset;
370c370,371
<                               $output .= "<div class='news-bulletin-time'>" . date("M j, Y g:i a",strtotime($row->cl_timestamp)) . "</div>";
---
>                               //Patched to display correct time in current time zone
>                               $output .= "<div class='news-bulletin-time'>" . date("M j, Y g:i a",strtotime($row->cl_timestamp) + ($wgLocalTZoffset * 60)) . "</div>";
```

How do I apply such as patch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the [`patch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) tool, with your file.

```
patch original.txt diffs.patch
```

This holds, if `diffs.patch` is a patch generated by `diff` without extra parameters (which your example appears to be). If you have a unified diff (`diff -u`) for example, you have to tell `patch` so by passing the appropriate flag (which is `-u` for unified diffs).